# Creating new tables automatically vs Giant table

Tags: android, sqlite

Im receiving throught BLE data stored in an SD Card. This data is organized in multiple text files, with each file corresponding to a date.
When receiving this data on android i want to save it on a SQlite database.
Thought about using the same logic, creating a table for each day. My question is if its possible to automatically create tables depending on the number of days that is going to be transfered. After some research i found how to add new tables using the onUpgrade method and changing the database version, but this seems only possible by changing the database version manually.
Another option would be by creating a single table for all the data, and add the date as a column.

Any feedback is valuable!

Comment: Use a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use a single table with the date as a column.

It would be possible to dynamically create tables, if they don't exist outside of the **onUpgrade** method. For each date/file you could, when receiving the file and before loading/inserting the data, either :-

1. use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the_table_with_a_name_that_relates_to_the_date (the_column_definitions)`

   - i.e. if the table exists then the above is effectively a NOOP.
2. use something like (the below assumes this method is in the DatabaseHelper)

:-

```
public bolean checkAndAddTable(String tableName) {
    boolean rv = false;
    SQLiteDatabase = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,"name=? AND type='table'",new String[]{tableName},null,null,null);
    if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(......SQL TO CREATE THE COLUMN DEFINITIONS......)");
        rv = true;
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- Note the code is in-principle code ans has not been run or tested and my therefore have some errors.

However, extracting the data from multiple tables would/should need to check if the table exists, to see if data can be extracted which would incur additional processing/complications (e.g. what to do if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a possibility, but i think ill just use a single table to hold the data. Ill mark this as accepted answer.